# Sublime Text 3 / LiveReload, Settings for Delay

Tags: delay, sublimetext, livereload

My apologies for asking this, but i did not figure out the solution by reading through the docs and/or the corresponding git-rep.

How can i enable a delay for LiveReload before it reloads the page?

Current Sublime-settings:

```
    { 
        "enabled_plugins": [ 
            "SimpleReloadPlugin", 
            "SimpleRefresh"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: it seems that these is no `SimpleRefresh` plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **preferences > package settings > LiveReload > Settings-Default**
and paste this code:

```
{
 "enabled_plugins": [
    "SimpleReloadPluginDelay"
 ]
}
```

it will enable the `400ms` delay plugin each time you start Sublime which refreshes the page after `400ms` of saving page.

Or enable this manually. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type `Livereload`. Select `LiveReload: Enable/disable plugins` and then select `Enable reload with delay (400ms)`.

Answer (score 0):

Must be "SimpleRefreshDelay"..

Been confused where to put the argument, but ended up just hard-coding it into SimpleReloadPluginDelay.py..